# Understanding how to measure the time complexity of a function

Tags: python, performance, big-o

This is the function:

```
c = []
def badsort(l):
  v = 0
  m = len(l)
  while v<m:
    c.append(min(l))
    l.remove(min(l))
    v+=1
  return c
```

Although I realize that this is a very inefficient way to sort, I was wondering what the time complexity of such a function would be, as although it does not have nested loops, it repeats the loop multiple times.

Comment: If it says "bad", it's almost always quadratic or worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Terminology

Assume that `n = len(l)`.

## Iteration Count

The outer loops runs n times. The `min()` in the inner loop runs twice over l (room for optimisation here) but for incrementally decreasing numbers (for each iteration of the loop, the length of l decrements because you remove an item from the list every time).

That way the complexity is `2 * (n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + (n-n))`.
This equals `2 * (n^2 - (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n))`.
The second term in the parenthesis is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) and diverges to `n*(n+1)/2`.

Therefore your complexity equals `2*(n^2 - n*(n+1)/2))`.
This can be expanded to `2*(n^2 - n^2/2 - n/2)`, 
and simplified to `n^2 - n`.

## BigO Notation

BigO notation is interested in the overall growth trend, rather than the precise growth rate of the function.

### Drop Constants

In BigO notation, the constants are dropped. This leaves us still with `n^2 - n` since there are no constants.

### Retain Only Dominant Terms

Also, in BigO notation only the dominant terms are considered. `n^2` is dominant over `n`, so `n` is dropped.

### Result

That means the answer in BigO is `O(n) = n^2`, i.e. quadratic complexity.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple of useful points to help you understand how to find the complexity of a function.

1. Measure the number of iterations
2. Measure the complexity of each operation at each iteration

For the first point, you see the terminating condition is `v < m`, where `v` is 0 initially, and `m` is the size of the list. Since `v` increments by one at each iteration, the loop runs at most (at least) `N` times, where `N` is the size of the list.

Now, for the second point. Per iteration we have -

```
c.append(min(l))
```

Where `min` is a linear operation, taking `O(N)` time. `append` is a constant operation.

Next,

```
l.remove(min(l))
```

Again, `min` is linear, and so is `remove`. So, you have `O(N)` + `O(N)` which is `O(N)`.

In summary, you have `O(N)` iterations, and `O(N)` per iteration, making it `O(N ** 2)`, or quadratic.

Comment: @RoadRunner Politics, revenge votes, etc. Sky's the limit ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The time compexity for this problem is `O(n^2)`. While the code itself has only one obvious loop, the `while` loop, the `min` and `max` functions are both `O(n)` by implementation, because at worst case, it would have to scan the entire list to find the corresponding minimum or maximum value. `list.remove` is `O(n)` because it too has to traverse the list until it finds the first target value, which at worst case, could be at the end. `list.append` is *amortized* `O(1)`, due to a clever implementation of the method, because `list.append` is technically `O(n)/n = O(1)` for `n` objects pushed:

```
def badsort(l):
  v = 0
  m = len(l)
  while v<m: #O(n)
    c.append(min(l)) #O(n) + O(1) 
    l.remove(min(l)) #O(n) + O(n)
    v+=1
  return c
```

Thus, there is:

```
Outer(O(n)) * Inner(O(n)+O(n)+O(n)) = Outer(O(n)) * Inner(O(n))
```

`O(n)+O(n)+O(n)` can be combined to simply `O(n)` because big o measures worst case. Thus, by combining the outer and inner compexities, the final complexity is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: You should explain why those lines are O(N), and what specifically contributes to it.

Comment: In the final line, you mentioned the final complexity is O(n) but in the first line, you mentioned O(n^2). What would be the overall time complexity?

Comment: Ok. That is great. Thanks!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That would be explaining specifically the implementation for `min`, `max`, `remove`, and `append`, which I believe is out of scope of the question.

Comment: No, you didn't understand. I just said to specifically mention why each line is O(N). For example, I did not see you mention that `remove` was O(N) when I wrote my comment. You added it in later.

Comment: Good, your answer is satisfactory. Quick nitpick: `transverse -> traverse`.

Comment: Shouldn't you multiply the time complexity for the inner and outer rather than add them?